# Failed upgrade, bad!

Tags: 16.04

I have a Toshiba Satellite M305-S49052 that was using 14.04. While on the internet I opted for the upgrade to 16.04. Half way through the upgrade it AbEnded. Now I have  door stop. What do I do now?

Comment: Failed upgrades are difficult to impossible to fix and a fresh install takes less time and is more reliable.

Comment: How do I do a fresh install with a computer that has no OS?  I have a mac air book running OS 10.12

Comment: Same way you did the first install, boot a live usb/cd and install.

Comment: I have no live usb/cd. I have a Mac Book Air running 10.12.6 Sierra. Can I use it to make a live USB for a Toshiba?

Comment: I think the answer depends upon the reason for the abnormal termination, and which step in the release-upgrade process was underway when termination took place. If termination occurred during downloading because of, say, a network error, then it's trivial to resume. If however, installing was taking place (which seems more likely if your system is now a brick), then a fresh reinstall is indeed the fastest and easiest way to resolve. If termination was due to a hardware problem, then reinstalling probably won't solve that underlying problem.

Comment: There is a method for creating a bootable USB for PCs on a MAC, covered at [https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0)